# ASP.NET Core MVC : view generation in controller folder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, when I click on the `View()`-- addView and provide the name `NewIndex.cshtml`, the file gets generated in the `Controller` folder but not in the `Views` folder...

Comment: Perhaps have you tried creating the Controller first, so that the View gets created?  The view depends on the controller, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you show us the dialog after clicking Add View?

Comment: @mj1313 no dialog box directly add the page in controller folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confusing, this is the process of adding pages to the controller action on my side, you may take a look.

In addition, you may update your VS to the latest version.

[image]